# Dereferencing the passed pointer to char array in the function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, char

I have a char array; char students[] = "John Maria Elisa Hans" and a pointer *pStudents pointing to that array. I need to pass this pointer into a function and use there as a char array. What exactly I mean is the pointer needs to be dereferenced in the function to be used as a char array. Indeed, I tried some ways to dereference the pointer, but no result was achieved. How can I achieve it?

Note: passing pointer, not the char array is a must.

Comment: "Indeed, I tried many ways to reference the pointer, but no result was achieved." Please show what you have tried.

Comment: like this; char *array = pStudents;

Comment: In c, the two are equivalent. If you declare the parameter as a pointer you can use array syntax to reference elements in the array that it points to.